# Is there a way to hide the bibliography "References" section altogether?

Tags: bibtex, natbib, bibentry

I have one bib file containing a full list of references, and show them in three different lists using `bibentry`.

For this to work, I need to add the bibliography file to the document, but this automatically inserts a "References" section in the document.

Is there a way to include the bibliography, but not show it explicitly?

MNWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\nobibliography*

\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@article{bla,
  title={blabla},
  author={me}
}
@book{blabook,
  title={blablabook},
  author={me}
 }  
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\section*{Some of my finest work}
\bibentry{bla}

\section*{A list of my books}
\bibentry{blabook}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\end{document}
```

I don't want all the entries duplicated in a "References" list, but I want bibentry to work. I also can't have a strong coupling between my document structure and separate bibliographies (like chapterbib or something), and I'd rather avoid multiple bibliographies altogether.

Comment: Can you add a MWE to play with?

Comment: @egreg there you go.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's almost as easy as changing `\nobibliography*` into `\nobibliography{<file>}`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{bla,
  title={blabla},
  author={me}
}
@book{blabook,
  title={blablabook},
  author={me}
 }
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\begin{document}
\nobibliography{\jobname}

\section*{Some of my finest work}
\bibentry{bla}

\section*{A list of my books}
\bibentry{blabook}

\end{document}
```

I used `\jobname` not to clobber files on my system, the argument to `\nobibliography` should be the one of your `.bib` file.

Note that the command *must* go after `\begin{document}`.

Comment: Brilliantly simple. I read the docs (bibentry and natbib), and found no mention of this. Thanks (again `:)`).

Answer (score 0):

egreg's solution gives me funny errors about list items, but the following works for me:

```latex
\hphantom{\vphantom{
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        \bibliography{mybibfile.bib}
    \end{minipage}
}}
```

Note that nesting `hphantom` and `vphantom` has the effect of typesetting the contents but replacing them with a 0x0 box. See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/269466/43137).

Without the minipage, I still get the errors about list items.