# APA Citation without Bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, apacite

I am writing my thesis using \documentclass{book} on overleaf. In order to perform plagiarism test, I have to remove the references but then all the citation, \citeauthor are replaced by question marks. Is there anyway to get author, year citation without the bibliography or references?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Have you tried placing `\clearpage` right before `\bibliography` -- and then deleting the bibliography page(s) from the pdf file?

Comment: With `biblatex`, you can also simply omit `\printbibliography`.

Comment: I am not using the \printbibliography command.  I have used \nobibliography but then citations are replaced by question marks.

Comment: How did you find `\nobibliography` command? [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Bibliography_management_in_LaTeX). You do not say how you are managing your bibliography: is it `apacite` (which can mask citations), or `natbib` or `biblatex` using natbib style, or `biblatex` using apa6 style, ..etc? Does [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229895/is-there-a-way-to-hide-the-bibliography-references-section-altogether) or [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31373/citations-with-no-bibliography-at-the-end) help? Note: It is really easy with `biblatex`.

Comment: i am using \usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}

Comment: I am using \usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}. the links you have mentioned are not working for me @Cicada

Comment: "not working for me" is not a helpful description: please supply small minimal example code that reproduces the issue (not your thesis), and put the code into the question, so that people can help and test solutions with.

Answer (score 1):

Using the solution in the linked questions, if the bib file is `testa.bib`, together with your `\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}` setting, then `\bibliography{testa.bib}` prints the bibliography and `\nobibliography{testa.bib}` does not print the bibliography.

Whenever bib data has changed between runs or on first run, remember to compile with the 3 steps: pdflatex (scan for bib data in document), bibtex (get bib data from bib file), pdflatex (print returned bib data).

MWE

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: bibtex
% arara: pdflatex

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{testa.bib}

@article{bla,
  title={blabla},
  author={me},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}

\usepackage{bibentry}




%============  document 
\begin{document}
xxx author citation: \citeauthor{bla}

\bibentry{bla}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{testa.bib} % prints the bibliography
%\nobibliography{testa.bib} % does not print the bibliography


\end{document}
```

With:

[image: apa with]

Without:

[image: apa without]